# How can I open my Android app with a custom link?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, deep-linking

I Wanna open My android app by links like WhatsApp and Telegram.

(example) `https://chat.whatsapp.com` if I Click this link and WhatsApp is installed this link will open WhatsApp So how can I do that in my app?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking and https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing for more on setting up app links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to deep link your app. For example: You open a link and it should be open through your app. In this case I use a website opened with a `webView` in your app. You can customize that of course.

Start to create an `<intent-filter>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
      <application
         <activity
            <intent-filter>
                   ...
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
                   
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="yourURL"></data>
                   ...
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
     </application>
```

And in your `MainActivity.java` you write the following code to get the data to be set in the `webView`:

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri!=null){
            String path = uri.toString();
            
            WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.loadUrl(path);
        }
```

And your `webView` defined in your `activity_main.xml`:

```
                 <WebView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/webView"/>
```

That's it. Good luck! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should define your base URL inside strings file like this :

```
<string name="base_url" translatable="false">yourapp.me</string>
```

after that you should define an IntentFilter inside Manifest file like this :

```
<activity android:name=".ExampleActivity">


<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">

<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

<data android:scheme="https" android:pathPrefix="/api" android:host="@string/base_url"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>
```

So your link should be like this :

```
https://yourapp.me/api
```

when you click on this link it should open your app in the activity that you put this intent filter inside it.